# Ventana tkinter con POO usando python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, tkinter, python-3.7

Resulta que estoy tratando de cargar una imagen a un label en una ventana tkinter hecha en POO, pero no aparece, sin usar POO si aparece, pero usando POO no aparece ¿Que hago?, estoy atorado, necesito ayuda, por  favor

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
from tkinter import PhotoImage
class Ventana(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.inicializar_gui()

    def inicializar_gui(self):
        self.title("APAGAR PC")
#       self.geometry("600x200")
        self.resizable(0,0)

        frm_izquierdo=tk.Frame(self,bg="red")
    

        imagen=PhotoImage(file="avion.gif")
        lbl_imagen=tk.Label(frm_izquierdo,image=imagen)
        lbl_imagen.grid(row=0,column=1)
   #    lbl_imagen['command']=self.Apagar

        frm_izquierdo.grid(row=0,column=0)
        frm_izquierdo.config(width=520,height=320)
     def Apagar(self):
        pass

def main():
    app=Ventana()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas una imagen dentro de esta función, ocurre ese mismo error. No recuerdo muy bien el motivo, pero si la forma de solucionarlo.

Tienes que hacer que la imagen se guarde en algún lugar que siga existiendo luego de la ejecución de la función (Las variables creadas dentro de una función son eliminadas cuando la ejecución termina).

Para lograr este objetivo se me ocurren dos formas:

## Hacerla global

Este es el método que menos recomiendo, pero te puede servir igual.

```
global imagen
imagen=PhotoImage(file="avion.gif")
```

Lo que hace este código es decirle a Python que estás creando una variable fuera de la función y también del class. Eso hace que la variable siga existiendo incluso cuando la función termina de ejecutarse.

## Hacer que sea un atributo del objeto Ventana

```
self.imagen=PhotoImage(file="avion.gif")
lbl_imagen=tk.Label(frm_izquierdo,image=self.imagen)
```

Lo que hace este código es crear el atributo "imagen" en la instancia de Ventana y guardar la imagen allí.